# Purpose of #!/bin/false in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

While working on a project written in bash by my former colleague, I noticed that all .sh files contain nothing but function definitions start with `#!/bin/false`, which is, as I understand, a safety mechanism of preventing execution of include-only files.

**Example:**

my_foo.sh

```
#!/bin/false
function foo(){
    echo foontastic
}
```

my_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

./my_foo.sh # does nothing
foo # error, no command named "foo"

. ./my_foo.sh 
foo # prints "foontastic"
```

However when I don't use `#!/bin/false`, effects of both proper and improper use are exactly the same:

**Example:**

my_bar.sh

```
function bar(){
   echo barvelous
}
```

my_script.sh

```
 #!/bin/bash

./my_bar.sh # spawn a subshell, defines bar and exit, effectively doing nothing
bar # error, no command named "bar"

. ./my_bar.sh
bar # prints "barvelous"
```

Since properly using those scripts by including them with `source` in both cases works as expected, and executing them in both cases does nothing from the perspective of a parent shell and generate no error message concerning invalid use, what is exactly the purpose of `#!/bash/false` in those script?

Comment: You said it yourself : with the `false` shebang, the content is not executed. It is a safety, in case the script is error-prone when used in the wrong context or ressource heavy. Most likely, it is an habit your colleague has picked up, that has no influence on the code in most cases but that could be usefull in more complex circumstances.

Comment: Also it should be worth noted that, the she-bang line `#!/bin/true` or `#!/bin/false` has no impact on the script when you invoke the shell interpreter directly as `bash my_script.sh`, this syntax runs the script with `bash` no-matter what and echoes the output `foontastic`

Comment: `./my_bar.sh` does not spawn a subshell : it spawns a whole new shell.  This is not just a technicality : subshells receive a copy of all variables of the main shell (including those that are not marked for export), while a separate shell receives only the exported variables.  Subshells are launched in other ways, for instance by enclosing statements parentheses `()`, initiating pipes `|`, process/command substitution `$()` `<()` `>()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, let’s consider a file `testcode` with bash code in it

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$0" = "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ]; then
  echo "You are executing ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
else 
  echo "You are sourcing ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
fi
```

you can do three different things with it:

```
$ ./testcode
You are executing ./testcode
```

This works if testcode has the right permissions and the right shebang. With a shebang of `#!/bin/false`, this outputs nothing and returns a code of 1 (false).

```
$ bash ./testcode
You are executing ./testcode
```

This completely disregards the shebang (which can even be missing) and it only requires read permission, not executable permission. This is the way to call bash scripts from a CMD command line in Windows (if you have `bash.exe` in your PATH...), since there the shebang machanism doesn’t work.

```
$ . ./testcode
You are sourcing ./testcode
```

This also completely disregards the shebang, as above, but it is a complete different matter, because *sourcing a script* means *having the current shell execute it*, while *executing a script* means *invoking a new shell to execute it*. For instance, if you put an `exit` command in a sourced script, you exit from the current shell, which is rarely what you want. Therefore, sourcing is often used to load function definitions or constants, in a way somewhat resembling the `import` statement of other programming languages, and various programmers develop different habits to differentiate between scripts meant to be executed and *include files* to be sourced. I usually don’t use any extension for the former (others use `.sh`), but I use an extension of `.shinc` for the latter. Your former colleague used a shebang of `#!/bin/false` and one can only ask them why they preferred this to a zillion other possibilities. One reason that comes to my mind is that you can use `file` to tell these files apart:

```
$ file testcode testcode2
testcode: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
testcode2: a /bin/false script, ASCII text executable
```

Of course, if these include files contain only function definitions, it’s harmless to execute them, so I don’t think your colleague did it to prevent execution.

Another habit of mine, inspired by the Python world, is to place some regression tests at the end of my `.shinc` files (at least while developing)

```
... function definitions here ...

[ "$0" != "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" ] && return 

... regression tests here ...
```

Since `return` generates an error in executed scripts but is OK in sourced scripts, a more cryptic way to get the same result is

```
... function definitions here ...

return 2>/dev/null || :

... regression tests here ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference in using `#!/bin/false` or not from the point of view of the parent shell is in the return code.

`/bin/false` always return a failing return code (in my case 1, but not sure if it is standard).

Try that :

```
./my_foo.sh //does nothing
echo $? // shows "1", a.k.a failing

./my_bar.sh //does nothing
echo $? // shows "0", a.k.a. everything went right
```

So, using `#!/bin/false` not only documents the fact that the script is not intended to be executed, but also produces an error return code when doing so.

Comment: Your second example is not correct, if my_bar.sh contains "exit 1". Also when including those files instead of executing (". ./my_foo", ". ./my_bar") return value is actually a return value of last executed command, so in order to use return values as safeguards I would need to end all include-only scripts with `true`.

Comment: The script `my_bar.sh`provided by OP doesn't include an `exit` command.
Also, the return code is just the return code of the script. The point being that using`#!/bin/false` will generate an erroneous return code.